# Character limit for multiple uitextfields

Tags: objective-c, textfield

I'm a fairly new programmer and am having trouble with some UITextfields, basically i have two text fields and i want to limit the amount of characters in one of them to a certain amount, whilst allowing the other field to have lots.

I found a post that recommended this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

   NSUInteger newLength = [[textField text] length] + [string length] - range.length;
   return (newLength > 2) ? NO : YES;

}
```

However that seems to affect both text fields. I'm not sure how to target one field.

Can anyone help, also one thing, i get whats going on in that code up until - range. length, is the range the total amount of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue here is that the object which contains this code is the delegate to both textfields. Two ways to solve it. Either dont add the textfield you dont care about the length of as a delegate or the better way would be to differentiate between the fields during the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method.

For the second part of your question- range is the character(s) that is/are being changed in the text field and consists of: The position of the string to change, the length of the string being changed.

My personal preference is to say if the text length is greater than max length and your not deleting then refuse the change.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if(textField == self.textfieldYouWantToLimitTheLengthOf){

        if(textField.text.length > 2 && ![string isEqualToString:@""]){

            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris that was an incredibly useful answer and description of the range function. I solved this (with the help of another real programmer :) ) in another manner, i just checked to see if the text field making the edits was the correct field based on its name, if this was the case the range check would be performed. however i can see your approach working perfectly too, so many thanks.

Comment: The logic to check the length is flawed. This only handles certain cases and will fail in many others.

Comment: @rmaddy The answer was more around switching between 2 text fields. Thought, please feel free to update my code sample to something more complete for anyone copy pasting.