# Two UITextFields First should not have characters limit second should have characters limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I m using method:

textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

There are two UITextFields. First should not have characters limit second should have characters limit.

Please help how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304151/character-limit-for-multiple-uitextfields

Comment: @SunilSharma The answer in the link is partially wrong. It doesn't handle lots of possible cases.

Comment: @rmaddy actually there are a lot of answer are available for this problem like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683376/textfielddidbeginediting-for-more-than-one-textfield and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865237/textfieldshouldreturn-for-multiple-textfields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following link [Set the maximum character length of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield)

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if (textField==secondTextField) {
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    return newLength <= 10;
} else{
    return YES;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Declare second Textfield as property (var secondTextField). And check it in func

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.secondTextField{
        if range.location > yourLimit{
         return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. 2. This code doesn't compile. 3. It doesn't actually limit the amount of text properly.